# How can I change my route into a function?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have an angular component, in which I have a function with another functions into.

I just want to change page when I click on a button which is draw in my function. I can not acces to the router declared in my component's constructor. So does anybody know how to do it ?

This is my component's code :

```
export class EncoursComponent{



  constructor(private serviceData : DataService, private router : Router) {
  }


  }

  //Fonction qui permet de dessiner les lignes et les points
  draw(id: any, events: any, options: any) {


    //Ici on définit les points
    svg.selectAll("circle")



      //I want that when I click, be redirected no another page
      .on("click", function(d: any) {
        var data : DataService = new DataService();

        //This line doesn't work
        var rout : Router = new Router();

        //I can't acces to this.router
        this.router.navigate("/affecter");


      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `function`s have their own scope. You can change `function` to an arrow function as follows

```js
    svg.selectAll("circle")



      //I want that when I click, be redirected no another page
      .on("click", (d: any) => {
        var data : DataService = new DataService();

        //This line doesn't work
        var rout : Router = new Router();

        //I can't acces to this.router
        this.router.navigate("/affecter");


      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your router in to your component like that

```
constructor (private router: Router) {}
```

Next I would change your inner function to an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to get the `this` scope of the class(your component).
Now you can navigate with `this.router.navigate('/path')`